# Need help to write regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I can't write regex so I really need your help trying to match the requirements. I have been so close but it always fail on small things.
This was the latest regex i tried:

```
/^\\{2}[-\w]+\\(([^"*/:?|<>\\,;[\]+=.\x00-\x20]|\.[.\x20]*[^"*/:?|<>\\,;[\]+=.\x00-\x20])([^"*/:?|<>\\,;[\]+=\x00-\x1F]*[^"*/:?|<>\\,;[\]+=\x00-\x20])?)\\([^"*/:?|<>\\.\x00-\x20]([^"*/:?|<>\\\x00-\x1F]*[^"*/:?|<>\\.\x00-\x20])?\\)*$/
```

But it ended up with not allowing me to put dots in server name.

I need this to be accepted:

```
\\servername.withdot\alowing spaces\1.2.3.4\under_scores\andNotEndWithBackslash
```

I will take any help I can get,

Thanks

Comment: please provide exact string you want to match and rules

Comment: Are you sure you don't want to just use [encodeURIComponent()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent)?

Comment: Check this Q: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9485091/php-regex-for-matching-a-unc-path

Comment: There are lots of regex testers online that would make this task easier for you, such as http://rubular.com/ or https://www.regexpal.com/

Comment: Tiny adaption of the answer in the Q I linked to here: https://regex101.com/r/cwKAr9/1

Answer (score 0):

You may try that:

```
^\\\\(?!\.)[\w\/\.-]+\\[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+\\(?!\.)[\d\.]+(?!\.)(\\\w+)+$
```

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/CexGxD/5/)

```js
const regex = /^\\\\(?!\.)[\w\/\.-]+\\[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+\\(?!\.)[\d\.]+(?!\.)(\\\w+)+$/;
const str = `\\\\servername.withdot\\alowing spaces\\1.2.3.4\\under_scores\\andNotEndWithBackslash`;
console.log(regex.test(str))
```